# Help: Visualforce Form Entry Test Class

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, community

Please help on this visualforce form entry test class. Below is what I have soon far.

Test Class:

```
 @isTest
public static testMethod void NetworkSitesCtrlTest() {
        PageReference pageRef = Page.Lead_Create;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);    

        Lead l = new Lead(Company='Tests');
        Test.startTest();
        NetworkSitesCtrl controller = new NetworkSitesCtrl(ApexPages.standardController(l));
        controller.createLead();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="NetworkSitesCtrl" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
    <apex:define name="body">
        <apex:form id="theForm">

            <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!NOT(showAuth)}">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.I_Agree_Submit_Application}" action="{!createLead}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.Company_Information}" columns="1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!leadRecord.Company}" label="{!$ObjectType.Lead.fields.Company.label}" required="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>
    </apex:define>
</apex:composition>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference createLead() {
    try {
        insert leadRecord;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPAges.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: I have to agree with @Bachovski here, if you aren't telling us what's challenging or blocking you .. how are we expected to know what we have to explain ? Please consider that we are here to help you make your code or config work, In order to do that, we have to know what is not clear to you specifically. Would you mind updating the question to include that ?

Comment: Sorry everyone.  I'm unable to compile.  Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ApexPages.standardController(Lead) at line 9 column 64